# Does express.js 4.x support node 4.x?

Tags: node.js, express, version

I've been trying to find the supported versions on node on the expressjs page, but can't find an official list. Has expressjs been updated to work with the newest releases of node?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2754) tracking this very point.

Comment: @Val - might as well make that an answer and perhaps summarize the status as of this particular date.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (Oct 09, 2015), the [`package.json`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/package.json#L76) file on the ExpressJS master branch still mentions that it supports node versions `>= 0.10.0`, so semantically speaking that would imply node 4.x.

However, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2754) dealing specifically with the node 4.x support. The current state is that express devs are trying to find which dependencies might have an issue running on node 4, but so far they've not found any.

So **in theory**, Express 4 should not have any issues running on Node 4.